# Why my session is not writable and create a loop?

Tags: php

I want to create a required login to acces `index.php` and other page but I have this error. My code makes a loop when I publish online on secure .com domain. Can someone help me? Thank you.

**index.php**

```
include "server.php";
session_start();
  
  if (isset($_SESSION["log"]) == 0) {
    header('location: login.php');
  }
```

**server.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  
    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }
 if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE name='$username' AND pass='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
                $_SESSION["log"] = $row['name'];
                header('location: index.php');
            }
        } 
      }
   }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Please show an example of your SQL query, and confirmation that such a record exists in the DB.

Comment: _"my code makes a loop"_ - You need to be _much_ more clear about what actually happens. Explain what you expect to happen and what actually happens (details).

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in plain text! You should only store password hashes generated using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and to verify a password againts a hash, use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 0):

Please start a session in `server.php`.

Because you start a session after `server.php`, it doesn't work.

You need to add `session_start();` at the top of `index.php`.

And you should not print anything in the buffer before `session_start()`.
Otherwise, it will raise a warning.

```
  session_start();
  include "server.php";
  
  if (isset($_SESSION["log"]) == 0) {
    header('location: login.php');
  }
```

Comment: i have already a session_start() in server.php and try it but have the same issue

Comment: on xampp is working, but when i publish online isn't working

Answer (score 0):

The session is not writable because the header has already been sent in server.php. The order you have to use is:

```
session_start();
// perform test to make sure user is logged in
// if not send to login page
header('location: login.php');
```